# Learning curve for noisy data

Tags: machine-learning, supervised-learning

I am doing a supervised classification of small texts, and the data is very noisy. I plotted a learning curve: x-axis is # instances. y-axis is the value of F-measure. The curve is falling: the more instances I use, the lower the F-measure score is. Is it typical for noisy data? Or there is some other reason for this behavior?

Comment: Can you share how the curve looks like?

Answer (score 1):

Did you calculate F-measure using training set or test set?

If you calculated it using training set then falling learning curve is pretty normal.

If you calculated it using test set then there may be many causes, the most probable is that training and test sets are not iid.

Comment: I used 10-fold cross-validation.